# 12.04 doesn't boot up after kernel update

Tags: 12.04, kernel, updates

I updated from 3.2.0-35 to 3.4 and now it just boots to a black screen after the BIOS. I have to press shift to bring up GRUB and go back to 3.2.0-35.

Any idea how I can get 3.4 to work? If not, how do I remove 3.4?

Also, did I download the right one? The file name says it's for AMD64, but Synaptic is saying it's for 32bit. What's up with that?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: @JorgeCastro I don't agree with closing it for this reason. The 3.4 kernel not working is a bug, yes, but the "how to revert to 3.2 permanently part" isn't.

Comment: How did you install this kernel? Did you use packages or did you compile it from source?

Comment: I got the ppa from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu doesn't boot after kernel update](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36439/ubuntu-doesnt-boot-after-kernel-update)

Answer (score 3):

You can remove 3.4 kernel via Synaptic. (+ info if someone hasn't it)

1. Install Synaptic with Ubuntu software center
2. Open Synaptic and press Ctrl + f
3. Write "linux image" without quotes and press enter
4. Look for something like linux-image-3.4-x-generic
5. Press right mouse button on it and select remove
6. Press "Apply changes" on the toolbar

Comment: That's what I thought. I didn't know if it would cause any problems.