# Reinstall kernals - I have two kernals that I cannot boot from

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I took an update from 4.15.0.33 to 4.15.0.34. My machine would not boot from the new kernel. I tried removing the latest kernel using: sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.15.0.34-generic and sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.15.0.34-generic. It successfully remove the kernel files and "update-grub2" show two remaining kernels (4.15.0.33 and 4.4.0.121).

When I reboot the machine continues to try and boot 4.15.34. How do I really kill it? In my messing around I can only successfully boot 4.4.0.121 now. How do I get things back to normal?

Answer (score 0):

For several days this virtual machine would only allow me to reboot, by manually selecting the older kernel 4.4.0.121 from the grub menu.

Not sure that this is a complete answer, but it may help someone else. I saw this post about reinstalling grub2 [Ubuntu doesn't boot after kernel update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36439/ubuntu-doesnt-boot-after-kernel-update?rq=1)

I decided to try reinstalling grub2 to see if it would finally update my grub menu. I executed "sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda". Low and behold my system now boots after manually removing the other kernels. I still have a minor issue with the grub boot menu not being visible during boot any more - progress.

Answer (score 0):

I had a send VM show the same problem. Latest Kernel didn't install properly.

This time I was able to `update-initramfs -u -k 4.15.0.39-generic` and `sudo update-grub2`

The latest kernel now boots. I still am missing the grub menu.